# Scrapping memory issue (Out Of Memory)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, video, out-of-memory

Good day,

I have cameras that are saving videos by clips on a cloud service, with a limit on N clips. In order to save more clips, I made a scrapping script that gets all my video links from the website where I can preview them. (to be executed on page load with a JS extension)

Note that these are M3U8 files.
Here is my script:

```
var cameraScrapper = {
    playerReady: false,
    videos: {},
    
    cameraCurrent: 0,
    cameras: [
        'cid1', // #1
        'cid2', // #3
        'cid3', // #2
    ],
    
    gui: function()  {
        return {
            calendarPreviousMonth: document.getElementById( 'event_calendar_section' ).getElementsByClassName( 'navigation' )[0].getElementsByClassName( 'prev' )[0],
            calendarNextMonth: document.getElementById( 'event_calendar_section' ).getElementsByClassName( 'navigation' )[0].getElementsByClassName( 'next' )[0],
            calendarSelectedDate: document.getElementById( 'event_selected_date' ),
            calendarMonthDays: document.getElementById( 'event_calendar_section' ).getElementsByClassName( 'month' )[0].children,
            cameras: document.getElementById( 'camera_list_dropdown' ).children,
            dayClips: document.getElementById( 'event_clips_wrap' ).children,
            noRecords: document.getElementsByClassName( 'no_recording' )[0]
        };
    },
    
    init: function() {
        document.getElementById( 'hls_player' ).addEventListener( 'canplay', function() { this.playerReady = true; }.bind( this ) );
        
        for( let i = 0; i < this.cameras.length; i++ ) {
            if( window.location.href.includes( '=' + this.cameras[i] + '&' ) ) {
                this.cameraCurrent = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        
        while( !this.gui().calendarPreviousMonth.children[0].classList.contains( 'disabled' ) ) {
            this.gui().calendarPreviousMonth.click();
        }
        
        this.scrap();
    },
    
    getVideo: function( pCamera, pTimeStamp ) {
        let performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {};
        let requests = ( performance.getEntries() || {} );
        
        for( let i = 0; i < requests.length; i++ ) {
            if( requests[i].name.includes( '.ts?' ) ) {
                if( this.videos[encodeURIComponent( requests[i].name )] === undefined ) {
                    this.videos[encodeURIComponent( requests[i].name )] = { 'camera': pCamera, 'timestamp': this.formatDate( pTimeStamp ) };
                }
            }
        }
        
        if( Object.entries( this.videos ).length > 25 ) {
            this.save();
            
            this.videos = {};
            performance.clearMarks();
            performance.clearMeasures()
            performance.clearResourceTimings();
        }
    },
    
    formatDate( pTimestamp ) {
        let date = pTimestamp.split( ' ' )[0];
        let time = pTimestamp.split( ' ' )[1];
        
        let month = {
            JAN: '01',
            FEB: '02',
            MAR: '03',
            APR: '04',
            MAY: '05',
            JUN: '06',
            JUL: '07',
            AUG: '08',
            SEP: '09',
            OCT: '10',
            NOV: '11',
            DEC: '12'
        }
        
        return date.split( '.' )[2] + '-' + month[date.split( '.' )[1]] + '-' + date.split( '.' )[0] + ' ' + time;
    },
    
    sleep: function( pMs ) {
        return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, pMs ) );
    },
    
    scrap: async function() {
        let scrapDays = true;
        
        while( scrapDays ) {
            for( let i = 0; i < this.gui().calendarMonthDays.length; i++ ) {
                if( !this.gui().calendarMonthDays[i].classList.contains( 'is-disabled' ) && !this.gui().calendarMonthDays[i].classList.contains( 'is-expired' ) && !this.gui().calendarMonthDays[i].classList.contains( 'is-future' ) ) {
                    // console.log( 'day ' + this.gui().calendarMonthDays[i].innerText );
                    
                    this.gui().calendarMonthDays[i].click();
                    
                    let clipsLoaded = false;
                    
                    if( this.gui().noRecords !== undefined ) {
                        clipsLoaded = !this.gui().noRecords.classList.contains( 'displayOff' )
                    }
                    
                    while( !clipsLoaded && ( this.gui().dayClips.length == 0 ) ) {
                        await this.sleep( 99 );
                        
                        if( this.gui().noRecords !== undefined ) {
                            clipsLoaded = !this.gui().noRecords.classList.contains( 'displayOff' )
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // console.log( 'clips ' + this.gui().dayClips.length );
                    
                    for( let j = 0; j < this.gui().dayClips.length; j++ ) {
                        this.playerReady = false;
                        this.gui().dayClips[j].children[0].click();
                        
                        while( !this.playerReady ) {
                            await this.sleep( 99 );
                        }
                        
                        this.getVideo( ( '' + this.cameraCurrent ), this.gui().calendarSelectedDate.innerText + ' ' + this.gui().dayClips[j].children[0].children[1].children[1].innerText );
                    }
                }
            }
            
            if( !this.gui().calendarNextMonth.children[0].classList.contains( 'disabled' ) ) {
                this.gui().calendarNextMonth.click();
            } else {
                scrapDays = false;
            }
        }
        
        this.save();
        
        this.sleep( 4999 );
        
        let cameraNext = this.cameraCurrent + 1;
        if( this.cameras.length >= cameraNext ) {
            cameraNext = 0;
        }
        
        window.location.href = 'https://cloudcamerasservice.com/camera?no=' + this.cameras[cameraNext] + '&model=CAM';
    },
    
    save() {
        let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open( 'POST', 'http://localhost/videomonitoring/stack.php', true );
        xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
        
        xhr.onload = ( e ) => { /* console.log( 'saved' ); */ };
        xhr.onerror = ( e ) => {};
        xhr.send( 'stack=' + encodeURIComponent( JSON.stringify( this.videos ) ) );
    }
};

setTimeout( function() { cameraScrapper.init() }.bind( this ), 4999 );
```

`stack.php` will handle file download from provided list, my script is mainly about getting the video links and date of recording.

But when launching my script, my browser run out of memory after 75-100 clips saved. Can you help me with this?

Not sure if it's comming from my script, indeed, I have the feeling this is due to preloading many videos on the same page.

Comment: I would suggest logging all your vars and checking if some are retaining data they shouldn't retain. The number of XHR requests can also eat RAM so that might be worth looking into.

Comment: @R.DeCaluwe thank you for your answer, I think around 2 or 3 XHR requests containing 25x (link, timestamp) are sent before it stucks, so not sure this is the reason. But can it be video requests as well?

I'll check for printing my variables but most of them are encapsulated variables or constants, I'll get back to you if any changes in my code issue.